# react api response crashes when having a different endpoint to the same url

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have two endpoints that I need to render, `response.data.data1` and `response.data.data2`,

the results array list works fine in the render if i comment out the description object output, but if I uncomment it the app crashes with An error and warning:

1. The above error occurred in the  component:Consider 
      adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error 
      handling behavior.
2. Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted 
      component.

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            results: {},
            spinning: false,
            description: {}
        };

        this.cancel = ''
    }
    /* take input query from user */
    performSearch = (query) => {
        const url = `url`
        if (this.cancel) {
            this.cancel.cancel();
        }

        this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();

        axios.get(url, {
                cancelToken: this.cancel.token
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    results: response.data.data1,
                    spinning: false,
                    description: response.data.data2
                })
                console.log(response)
                /* handle error*/
            }).catch(err => {
                if (axios.isCancel(err) || err) {
                    console.log('Error: ', err.message);
                    this.setState({
                        spinning: false
                    })
                }
            })
    }
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const query = event.target.value
        if (!query) {
            this.setState({
                query,
                results: {},
                description: {}
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                query,
                spinning: true,
            }, () => {
                this.performSearch(query)
            })
        }
    }
    showSearchResult = () => {
        const { results, description } = this.state
        if (results.length) {
            return (
                <div >
                    {/*<div >
                        <h4>{description.name} </h4>
                    </div>*/}
                    <ul>
                        { results.map( item => {
                            return (
                                <div  key={ item.word }>
                                    <li >
                                        <h4 >{item.word}</h4>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            )
                        } ) }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { query, spinning } = this.state
        return (
            <div >
                <label  htmlFor="search-input">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="query"
                        value={query}
                        id="search-input"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                </label>
                { this.showSearchResult() }             
                <img 
                    src={ Spinner }     
                    className={`spinner-icon ${ spinning ? 'show' : 
                        'hide' }`}
                    alt="Spinner gif"/>

               </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `response.data` look like?

Comment: console.log(response.data)

{
  “data2”: {
    “name”: “abc”,
    “Phone”: 222,
    “AdditionalInfo”: 4,
  },
  “data1”: [
    {
      "word": “apple”,
    },
    {
      "word": “banana”
     ,
    {
      "word": “lemon”,,
    {
  ],
}
---i have to edit and add someother characters since, I can't put it out there

Comment: Your code is seems to be working fine. What is exact issue? Can't you create a codepen for this?

Comment: response.data sometimes doesn't show data2, that is when it crashes. And also before i finish entering any input it crashes as well

Comment: It means the issue is from backend and not in your code.

Comment: You can handle this in your code like, `{description && <div >
                        <h4>{description.name} </h4>
                    </div>}`. this will make sure if your description has data then only it will show you the name.

Comment: everything works fine without crashing if i comment out {description.name}

Comment: Did you check my comment? You need to wrap your `description.name` in a condition.

Comment: {description && <div > <h4>{description.name} </h4> </div>} ---seems to be working, it didn't crash for few input entries.

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: Let me answer this.

Comment: Hi user, check my answer for detail description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state is an empty object,

```
description: {}
```

So when you try to access it like,

```
<div >
   <h4>{description.name} </h4>
</div>
```

It simply checks if `description` object contains `name` key. If yes then it simply prints it otherwise it will throw an error.

As per your comment, *response.data sometimes doesn't show data2, that is when it crashes.* **If `data2` itself is not present then you `description` object will remain empty.** So accessing value from empty object will always throw you error.

To solve this you need to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) values from description object.

```
{description && <div>
    <h4>{description.name} </h4>
  </div>
}
```

Here we have use `Logical && Operator`. It means that, if `description` object contains data then only your `div` will get render otherwise `React` won't add that `div` in the document.